# expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '*' token

Tags: c++, c, mingw-w64

I am trying to build in MinGW (this builds fine in VS2005) but facing this error at:

```
#ifndef int64
#define int64 __int64 /**< Win32 version of 64-bit integers */
#endif

// also in class.h
#ifndef FADDR
#define FADDR
typedef int64 (*FUNCTIONADDR)(void*,...); /** the entry point of a module function */
#endif
```

and the error I get is:

```
 error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '*' token
 typedef int64 (*FUNCTIONADDR)(void*,...); /** the entry point of a module function */
                ^
```

Any suggestions about how to handle this?
Thank you.

Comment: #ifndef int64
#define int64 __int64 /**< Win32 version of 64-bit integers */
#endif

Comment: Win32 version of 64-bit integers. Basically when I run this using MSVS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`__int64` is [part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/29dh1w7z.aspx) from MSVC and doesn't exist in GCC. You can use `int64_t` from `stdint.h` instead. Simple check:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
typedef __int64 int64;
#else
#include <stdint.h>
typedef int64_t int64;
#endif
```

Comment: It'd be preferable to use `typedef` rather than `#define`.

Comment: I believe recent versions of MSVC support `<stdint.h>`. Unless you need to support older releases of MSVC, it's probably best to use it, since it's defined by the language standard.

Comment: I tried the above, it did not work. So, I changed typedef int64 (*FUNC...) call to typedef __int64(*FUNC...) and it worked. Is anything wrong with this way of doing?